# Problem while recovering public key from transaction on ethereum

Tags: key, ethereum, public

I am currently trying to get public key from an ethereum account using one of its transaction and https://toolkit.abdk.consulting/ethereum

Here is the info I have about the contract :

```
{
    from: "0x9acadffa3d622b6f77b2dd625ad41e054eec300e",
    gas: 2000000,
    gasPrice: Object { s: 1, e: 10, c: Array [ 50000000000 ] },
    hash: "0x6799103870e88fc59a9dc5f400dfd2fb5fed82b58fbffb09a99808003ee2634d",
    input: "0x",
    nonce: 3,
    r: "0xe58712e11aaa32ac207e893cde3b91159c1e1dc5be5a9bd18f0476869806feb6",
    s: "0x421eef8f63fc2872c86d79048ac053542980768f4b7638da40353c0a95012473",
    to: "0xafb1e5c639950c547473de7dc5afb8d8cea0658c",
    v: "0x1c",
    value: Object { s: 1, e: 15, c: Array [ 10 ]}
}
```

I thought that putting these values in ABDK would give me the raw hex data of the transaction, and then give me the public key.

However, with the raw hex data, I get alternatively the good hash and the good address depending on putting the decoding mode to Transaction or to Hex.
I am really confused, because the two good values appears, but not on the same time at the same place.

Here is the raw data that I got :

`0xf86c03850ba43b7400831e848094afb1e5c639950c547473de7dc5afb8d8cea0658c87038d7ea4c68000801ca0e58712e11aaa32ac207e893cde3b91159c1e1dc5be5a9bd18f0476869806feb6a0421eef8f63fc2872c86d79048ac053542980768f4b7638da40353c0a95012473`​

Thank you by advance for your help !

​

Answer (score 0):

And here it is. Your address has no official transactions tough. How did you manage to get those values?

[image: Recovering public key from transaction on Ethereum]